# How do I reliably get variable from child

Tags: powershell

I am building a sql Job Generator in Powershell. My PS skills aren't the greatest,

I want to get a value created in function CreateSqlTask. The variable I want is $job. I get an array of objects back from this function.

```
#My call  
$returnParams = CreateSqlTask ( LIST OF PARAMS)
```

### $returnParams[0] is the value of the jobSchedule Creation $returnParams[1] is the variable I want, this is the value of $job .

as a programmer I do not believe it is relable to just assume $returnParams[1] is always the variable I need. What is the proper way to handle this case?

```
 #Here is the function implementation:
function CreateSqlTask
{    

    Param ( LIST OF PARAMS   )

    #Make all errors terminating
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    #Create the SQL Job
    $job = CreateSqlJob -serverInstance $serverInstance -jobName $jobName -jobDesc $jobDesc -jobCategory $jobCategory -jobAlertOperator $jobAlertOperator -jobEmailLevel $jobEmailLevel

    #Create the SQL Job Step
    $jobStep = CreateSqlJobStep $job $stepName $stepCmd

    #Alter the Job to tell it what step should execute first
    $job.StartStepID = $jobStep.ID
    $job.Alter()

    #Create the SQL Job Schedule
    CreateSqlJobSchedule $job `
                            $schedName `
                            $schedFreqType `
                            $schedFreqRecurFactor `
                            $schedFreqInterval `
                            $schedFreqSubDayType `
                            $schedFreqSubDayInterval `
                            $startingSchedHour `
                            $startingSchedMinute `
                            $endingSchedHour `
                            $endingSchedMinute

    return $job     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out, both `CreateSqlJobSchedule` and `return $job` are returning values.  If you need both of these then I suggest you assign these to a new object:

```
$jobDetails = @{
    CreateSqlJob = $CreateSqlJob             
    CreateSqlJobSchedule = $CreateSqlJobSchedule
}

return $jobDetails
```

The above assumes you have assigned the two calls to two variables, you can then refer to them by name:

```
$createSqlTaskResults = CreateSqlTask
$createSqlTaskResults.CreateSqlJob 
$createSqlTaskResults.CreateSqlJobSchedule
```

Here's how it would look in your example:

```
 #Here is the function implementation:
function CreateSqlTask
{    

    Param ( LIST OF PARAMS   )

    #Make all errors terminating
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    #Create the SQL Job
    $CreateSqlJob = CreateSqlJob -serverInstance $serverInstance -jobName $jobName -jobDesc $jobDesc -jobCategory $jobCategory -jobAlertOperator $jobAlertOperator -jobEmailLevel $jobEmailLevel

    #Create the SQL Job Step
    $jobStep = CreateSqlJobStep $job $stepName $stepCmd

    #Alter the Job to tell it what step should execute first
    $job.StartStepID = $jobStep.ID
    $job.Alter()

    #Create the SQL Job Schedule
    $CreateSqlJobSchedule = CreateSqlJobSchedule $job `
                            $schedName `
                            $schedFreqType `
                            $schedFreqRecurFactor `
                            $schedFreqInterval `
                            $schedFreqSubDayType `
                            $schedFreqSubDayInterval `
                            $startingSchedHour `
                            $startingSchedMinute `
                            $endingSchedHour `
                            $endingSchedMinute

    $jobDetails = @{
        CreateSqlJob = $CreateSqlJob             
        CreateSqlJobSchedule = $CreateSqlJobSchedule
    }

    return $jobDetails   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function should return only one type of object. If you don't need the job creation return, you can send that output to $null or assign it to a variable within the function.  If you do need that along with the other information I'd create a custom object or hash table that includes that information along with the job information and return that.

Comment: Although I have given an answer to your specific question, take on board what @mjolinor is saying as you will end up with cleaner code in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is within the CreateSQLJob function to return a custom object that includes the pertinent information you want.

For instance:

```
$job = New-Object Object
$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty serverInstance -value $serverInstance
$obj | Add-Member Noteproperty jobName  -value $jobName
```

Then you would be able to call into those properties:

```
$obj.jobName
```

The above is a contrived example.